# Kubernetes With DPDK

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to figure out if Kubernetes will work for a certain use case. I understand the networking/clustering concept, and even the load balancing and how that can be used with things like nginx. However, assuming this is not deployed on a public cloud and things like ELB won't be available, could it still be used for a high-speed networking application using DPDK? For example, if we assume the cluster networking provided by k8s is only used for the control/management path, and the containers themselves handle the NIC directly with DPDK, is this something it's commonly used for?

Secondly, I understand the replication controller and petsets feature I think, but I'm not really clear on whether the intent of those features is for high availability or not. It seems that the "pod fails and the RC replaces it on a different node" isn't necessarily for HA, and there aren't really guarantees on how fast it builds a new pod. Am I incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, if the replication controller has size large than 1, it is highly available.

For example, you have an service "web-svc" in front of the replication controller "web-app", with size 3, then your request will be load balanced to one of the 3 pod:

web-svc ----> {web-app-pod1, web-app-pod2, web-app-pod3}

If some of the 3 pods fail, kubernetes will replace them with new ones.

And pet set is similar to replication controller, but used for stateful applications like database.

Comment: Pao, thanks for the reply. Do you know typically how long it takes to replace a container? The reason I ask is sometimes HA means a standby will keep state and take over immediately if the network traffic routes to it. In this case we'd be starting up a new container, pushing config, etc.

Comment: Emm... when you say "replace", you mean "rolling udpate"?

Comment: Not a rolling update, but when a pod fails and the rc starts another, how long would this take typically? Is it not designed for fast failovers?